# Cannot find class in classpath: net.mycompany.myproj.scripts.programs.MyClass

Tags: macos, terminal, testng

I am running below command

user$ java -cp testng-6.11.jar:jcommander-1.7.jar org.testng.TestNG /path-to-my-testng/mytestng.xml

but I am getting error:
[TestNG] [Error]
Cannot find class in classpath: net.mycompany.myproj.scripts.programs.MyClass